# Codename One connect css stylesheet

Tags: css, codenameone, stylesheet

I am trying to use a css style sheet with a Codename one application.

So far I have downloaded the cn1css-ant-task.jar file and added it to the lib folder of my project. Further on, I followed the instructions given at https://www.codenameone.com/blog/rounded-corners-shadows-and-gradients-with-css.html and here https://github.com/shannah/cn1-css/wiki/Installation. Due to a conflict with node, I have chosen the Manual Installation.

The css-file is there but its contents don't reflect on the style of the application, so I presume the css file is not properly connected.

I have spent quite some hours on the net to figure out a solution, but to no avail.

To better show what I already have, I am adding a few screenshots. Help would be greatly appreciated.

[image][image][image]

Comment: When you build the project or run it, do you see any output in the console for the "compile-css" task?  Looking at your CSS file, it should pop up with a window showing some of the image borders being generated during the build.  Did that occur?  Did you intend for the "button" CSS class to change the background color of buttons?

Comment: It looks like you are on Linux. Make sure you are using Oracle JDK for the CSS calls/IDE. I was also advised that installing the OpenJFX package should work too with Open JDK  but I haven't tried that.

Comment: @stevehannah, thanks for your reply. I have checked the compiler output and seen an error message saying: Not compiling ... /css/theme.css because ..... Calendar/src/theme.css.res has a newer modification time. Also, I don't see any change whatsoever in any item of the application. Is it necessary to connect the objects through UIIDs with the css file?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, thanks for your reply. Checking the java version, it is Oracle Java 8, JDK 1.8. And yes, I am using Linux.

Comment: @stevehannah, with the "button" css class I was trying to modify the general buttons' appearance, just for a test. "Round1" I have added randomly ..... is a general configuration class or attached to an object with the same UIID?

Comment: "Not compiling ... /css/theme.css because ..... Calendar/src/theme.css.res has a newer modification time".  Delete your theme.css.res file and build again.  Sometimes this happens.  The css library errs on the side of safety when it comes to overwriting the res file.  Just in case you have made manual changes to it, it won't overwrite it if the modification time is newer than the css file.  WRT "button".  It needs to be "Button" not "button".  In addition, if you are setting the background color only,  you will need to set border:none; background:none; in case an image border is set.

Comment: Steve, getting closer  ... got the css style sheet working by deleting the theme.css.res file every time I get an error message. Also, the css file seems to be working only when located in the root directory, not the src folder. One more small issue persists:, though: the "Button" class affects the cells in the table, but not the generic button I have in the application (Button { background-color: lightcoral; border:none; }. Is this intended or is there another class to access the "normal" button?

Comment: The css file goes in the css directory.  Not the src directory.  When it is compiled, it will place a resulting .res file in your src directory.  For the buttons, you likely also need background:none.    This is because the native theme may have an image background.  The order or precedence:  1. Image border.  2.  Image background.  3. Background color.  So if you set the background color but the native theme sets either an image border or image bg, you won't see your background color.

Comment: Ok, got it figured out. Many thanks for your help. You guys do a terrific support job ...

Comment: I am getting one additional error message: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module" ... is this related to compiling the project, or a gnome configuration?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that one.  Can you post the full error in context?

Comment: Steve, the error message  "Gtk-Message: Failed to load module - unity-gtk-module" shows when I first change some item of the css file .. but does not reappear when I rerun the application without making new changes to the css file. The changes to the css file are computed correctly and there seems not to be no impact the functioning of the app. Maybe the message is irrelevant (if such thing exists)?

Comment: I would ignore it then.